# Grouping multiple bounding boxes

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv, background-subtraction

I am using background subtraction to detect movement on the screen then I use cvFindContours to detect contours when I use cvBoundingRect I get a lot of small rectangle this is due to background subtraction does not return smooth connected binary image there are holes in the diff image which causes a lot of little rectangles. My question is how can I group these little rectangles in to a bigger rectangle around the whole movement.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how disconnected are your detected contours, 
you could try to smooth your Image using [cvSmooth](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/image_filtering.html?highlight=cvsmooth#cvSmooth) and then apply some morphological operators such as Dilation ([cvDilate()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/image_filtering.html?highlight=cvDilate#cvDilate)) and Closing ([cvMorphologyEx()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/image_filtering.html?highlight=cvsmooth#morphologyex)).

cvDilate() for example takes an IplConvKernel produced by CreateStructuringElementEx and you can make a structuring element that best suits your needs.